# Stuck while returning value from map

Tags: java

I have below method which returns a map.

```
private Map<String, FilterParam> retrieveFilter(Map<String, String> params) {

    Map<String, FilterParam> filterParams = new HashMap<>();


    for(Entry<String, String> e : params.entrySet()){
        if(someOthermap.containsKey(e.getKey())){
            filterParams.put(e.getKey(), parser.parse(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));

        }
    }

    return filterParams;
}

public class FilterParam {

public FilterParam parse(String key, String value){

    FilterParam filterParam = new FilterParam();
    filterParam.setKey(key);

    if(value.length() > 1 && value.startsWith("$")){
        filterParam.setOperator(Operator.PROCESS);
        filterParam.setValue(value.substring(1));

    }else{
        filterParam.setOperator(Operator.QUIT);
        filterParam.setValue(value);
    }

    return filterParam
    }
}
```

My issue is, when filterparams returning value, it has value something like

> {name=com.test.FilterParam@15db9742}

which is correct, however I want to get the actual value of map like

> (name=Chuna)

where key=name and value=Chuna

which is possible If I change the return type of method parse(String, String) from FilterParam to String, than easily I can get it the value.

Here, my requirement says don't change the return type but get the value from map instead of object.

I am confuse how to get the value! Please anyone guide me.

Comment: Digging java yourself a bit will definitely help!

Comment: Yeah Arjun, you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override a `toString()` method on a `FitlerParam` class.

The default `toString()` implementation concatenates package name, class name, `@` and object's hashCode in hexadecimal base, you don't want that, so you need to provide your own implementation.

Comment: It's a basic thing, I should have dig more.